# I would like to convert my project English to Arabic

Tags: java

I have tried the following king of code but it does not works. I do know how to proceed.

```
public class JavaApplication2 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, GoogleAPIException {
        Translator translate = Translator.getInstance();
        String text = translate.translate("Hello!", Language.ENGLISH, Language.ROMANIAN);
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

It does not work

Comment: Are you getting any error? If yes, can you post it here?

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "it does not work" ?

Comment: So you are translating from English to Romanian but it does not show Arabic? weird...

Comment: Sorry I m tring Varies Language , So That I changed as ROMANIAN , ACTUALLY I NEED ARABIC.

Comment: Error : Can't find symbol getInstance() and Can't find method translate

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
String translatedText = Translate.DEFAULT.execute("Text", 
Language.ENGLISH, Language.ARABIC);
```

Taken from the [Google translate website](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/)

Although it seems that project is archieved so i am unsure is it supported anymore maybe look at the [Translate V2](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/translate/v2)

Comment: Error: [google-api-translate-java] Referrer is not set. Call setHttpReferrer().

Comment: I got these above erroe while running code String translatedText = Translate.DEFAULT.execute("Text", 
Language.ENGLISH, Language.ARABIC);

Comment: Yes i only added the snippet i thought you were missing on the site i linked you need to set your sites http before using it. And also the API key